# Need help with subdivision surface

Tags: modifiers

I was trying to add the subdivision surface to this object so I can later add a displacement modifier, but when I add it, even on Simple it creates some weird geometry bugs, can someone help?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/htnd0.jpg

[image]

Comment: could you post .blend file of just the wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because how the mesh is shaped as it contains ngons so if you would add subsurf modifier it would create weird geometry
[image]

try creating a good mesh without tris and ngons just with quads.

Here I've converted ngons to tris and quads by selecting all the ngons and Hit <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> in Edit Mode. Then ngons will be converted to tris and quads.
[image]

Then by bevel edges you can see that some of the shape remains same.. 
[image]

So, the solution is to create a new mesh with good geometry just with quads if possible. and bevel all the edges that curve when subsurf modifier is used.

If you can create the mesh its great. If not try using [Booltool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rmvl0xVsA_o) addon it would save lot of time in creating these kind of meshes.